# IE11 div height is not calculated correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have the following [code snippet](https://jsbin.com/voqaqojupu/1/edit?html,css,output) which renders perfectly fine on chrome, however on IE11 the height of `.wrapper` div element isn't being calculated correctly.

what would the fix for `IE11` entail? I've tried looking around for fixes but couldn't find the one that definitively fixes this issue.

Comment: Flex aren't very well supported in IE11 there are bugs that's my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove display:flex; flex;1 css line for selector .container

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}


.wrapper {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #f17e5d 35%, #f6d365 100%);
  padding: 80px 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 455px;
  top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.headline {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.orderedList {
    font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  padding: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: -28px;
  margin: 0;
}

.listItem {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.listContent {
    padding: 1px;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="headline">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to .
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to .Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to .
  </div>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="orderedList">
        <li class="listItem">
          <p class="listContent">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
          </p>
        </li>
                <li class="listItem">
          <p class="listContent">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
          </p>
        </li>
                <li class="listItem">
          <p class="listContent">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
          </p>
        </li>
                <li class="listItem">
          <p class="listContent">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
          </p>
        </li>
      </ol>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

removing `flex:1` from your `.container` `css` solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

As https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox (see Known Issues):

> In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property.